# How to display 10000 div in one line using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to display 10000 div in one line using javascript or jquery?
I want to display 10000 div in one line without break a line.

```js
 (function callBox() {
        "use strict";
        var i, j, mainCube, a, div, elements;
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".mainCube");
        mainCube = [];
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            mainCube[i] = a = [];
            for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                // Create this div
                mainCube[i][j] = div = document.createElement('div');

                // Add class and such to div
                div.className = "letterPix";

                // Append it to the mainCubeClass element
                elements[i].appendChild(div);
            }
        }
        })();
```

```css
.mainCube {
        border: 2px solid rgb(204, 31, 0);
        }

        .letterPix {
        border: 1px solid rgb(15, 14, 14);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="mainCube"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add `white-space:nowrap;` to main cube class

```js
(function callBox() {
        "use strict";
        var i, j, mainCube, a, div, elements;
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".mainCube");
        mainCube = [];
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            mainCube[i] = a = [];
            for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                // Create this div
                mainCube[i][j] = div = document.createElement('div');

                // Add class and such to div
                div.className = "letterPix";

                // Append it to the mainCubeClass element
                elements[i].appendChild(div);
            }
        }
        })();
```

```css
.mainCube {
        border: 2px solid rgb(204, 31, 0);
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow-y:auto;
        }

        .letterPix {
        border: 1px solid rgb(15, 14, 14);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="mainCube"></div>
```

i add overflow for style but is not necessary